# animate print out of linked list of a c code program

Tags: c, linked-list, printf, pretty-print

I have a program that

- create link list
- manipulate multiple node values in the node
- print sorted link list node values

I like to integrate my C code with a library to show my printf as a graph

- **while (node->next != NULL) print node->value**

this change that to:

- **while (node->next != NULL) show graph of node->value**

for now : I print in the terminal a boxes as printf   [1:3:4] -> [3:3:4] -> [4:6:5] ->

Comment: Recommendation (assuming this is a school assignment): Do the assignment only. Don’t get distracted with things above and beyond. Your current printout to the terminal is sufficient. Save doing cool fancy graphics and stuff for your own projects.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Graphviz](https://graphviz.org/) for this purpose. It's open-source, multi-platform, easy to write out directions in a text file, and it does all the placement of nodes automatically.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node;
struct list { struct node *head, *tail; };
struct node { struct node *next, *prev; };

static char *name(const struct node *const node) {
    static char buffer[2][64];
    static unsigned b;
    b++, b %= 2;
    if(!node) {
        strcpy(buffer[b], "node_null");
    } else {
        sprintf(buffer[b], "node_%p", (const void *)node);
    }
    return buffer[b];
}

static void graph(const struct list *const list) {
    const struct node *node;
    unsigned label = 1;
    printf("digraph {\n"
        "\tgraph [rankdir=LR, truecolor=true, bgcolor=transparent,"
        " fontname=modern];\n"
        "\tnode [fillcolor=\"Gray95\", fontname=modern,"
        " style=filled, shape=box];\n"
        "\tlist:tail -> %s"
        " [color=\"royalblue4\", style=\"dotted\", arrowhead=\"empty\"];\n"
        "\tlist:head -> %s [color=\"royalblue\"];\n",
        name(list->tail), name(list->head));
    printf("\tlist [label=<\n"
        "<table border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">\n"
        "\t<tr><td align=\"left\" border=\"0\">"
        "<font color=\"Gray75\">list</font></td></tr>\n"
        "\t<hr/>\n"
        "\t<tr><td port=\"tail\" border=\"0\" align=\"left\">tail</td></tr>\n"
        "\t<tr><td port=\"head\" border=\"0\" align=\"left\""
        " bgcolor=\"Grey95\">head</td></tr>\n"
        "\t<hr/>\n"
        "\t<tr><td></td></tr>\n"
        "</table>>, style=none, shape=plain];\n");
    for(node = list->head; node; node = node->next) {
        printf("\t%s [label=\"%u\"];\n", name(node), label++);
        printf("\t%s -> %s [color=\"royalblue\"];\n",
            name(node), name(node->next));
        printf("\t%s -> %s [color=\"royalblue4\", style=\"dotted\","
            " arrowhead=\"empty\"];\n",
            name(node), name(node->prev));
    }
    printf("\tnode_null [shape=none, style=none, label=\"null\"];\n"
        "\tnode [colour=\"red\"];\n"
        "}\n");
}

int main(void) {
    struct list list;
    struct node node[6];
    list.head = node + 0, list.tail = node + 5;
    node[0].next = node + 1, node[0].prev = 0;
    node[1].next = node + 2, node[1].prev = node + 0;
    node[2].next = node + 3, node[2].prev = node + 1;
    node[3].next = node + 4, node[3].prev = node + 2;
    node[4].next = node + 5, node[4].prev = node + 3;
    node[5].next = 0, node[5].prev = node + 4;
    graph(&list);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Piping `stdout` into `graph.gv` and opening with Graphviz shows, (it uses `dot` as the default layout engine):

[image: The output from the programme piped into Graphviz.]

It now supports UTF-8 and you can also include this in your LaTeX files directly using [the graphviz package](https://ctan.org/pkg/graphviz?lang=en). It probably has an installer in your favourite package manager.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply .  how to compile my c code to use this library and run it ? i installed the package on my ubuntu but running the code printed the printf as it is . (im guessing i need to do extra steps to run it with the graphical package).   i want to replace my code of ( while node->next != NULL ) print xxx to use this library

Comment: Oh, should have explained that: not a library, it's directly in the Graphviz format, which you can pipe to a file, `a.out > graph.gv`. You can then open it in the GUI, `graphviz graph.gv`, or `dot` is the command line utility that turns it into a a standard format. A more complex programme might accept a file name or file descriptor to dump the graph at a certain time into using `fprintf`.